# Converting second order equation to first order equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I convert the following second order equation to a first order?

$$ u'' + 3u' - 4.5u = -2.5\sin(3t) $$

I have let $v=u'(t)$, but not sure what $v'(t)$ would look like.

$$ u' = v $$
$$ v' = ??? $$

My attempt:

$$ u'' = v' = -2.5sin3t - 3v + 4.5u$$

Surely the $4.5u$ piece can be substituted in terms of v?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: since $v=u^\prime$, we have $v^\prime=u^{\prime\prime}$.  Thus we must solve for $u^{\prime\prime}$ in the original equation:

$$
v^\prime=u^{\prime\prime}=-2.5\sin(3t)-3u^\prime+4.5u
$$

This should get you started.

Comment: $u''=-2.5sin(3t)-3u'+4.5u=-2.5sin(3t)-3v+4.5u = v'$ Can it be substituted further?

Comment: No, that is sufficient.  You now have a system with $(u,v)$ as the unknowns.